# Easy way to load Visual Studio 2012 reference?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, reference

I want to load all the reference dll from an old project to a new project.

Is there any way like 'one-click to add all'
otherwise i have to find and add them one by one...

Comment: Open the project files in a text editor and copy/paste the reference elements.  You can make that zero clicks if you use the keyboard.

Comment: Why not just open the project in 2012?

Comment: @iamkrillin I don't think that's the issue. I believe OP is trying to create a new project with the same project dependencies

Answer (score 2):

[Productivity Power Tools 2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd) has a Copy/Paste References feature.

Another way is to open the project files in a text editor and copy/paste the references you want from the old project to the new one.